# Can MAAS be used to deploy Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode?

Tags: ubuntu, uefi, maas

Supermicro is telling me that with the latest BIOS update on my blade server, that I can only boot from NVMe drives if I set the BIOS to “UEFI” boot mode and then install Ubuntu in EFI in boot mode.

I made the BIOS change, but have no idea how to tell MAAS to configure Ubuntu to boot in UEFI mode. I was hoping it would detect that my server only supported UEFI and automatically handle this properly. The MAAS deploy looks like it’s working, but then when it reboots at the end (or at least what I assume is the end), it just dumps into a “UEFI Interactive Shell” and the deploy fails:

[image: UEFI Interactive Shell]

Comment: This question didn't get any traction here, but I was able to get a discussion started over here: https://discourse.maas.io/t/can-maas-be-used-to-deploy-ubuntu-in-uefi-boot-mode/7594/8 ...which will hopefully end in a solution. I will try to remember to report back here if a solution is found.